# Rails controller can not use Model instance method on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I have a rails app that is built to map attributes dynamically. This method is run during the create action. For some reason my Rspec examples will pass but my Cucumber scenario fails now that I have implemented this method.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    def method_missing(method, *args)
        if method.to_s['=']
          self.define_singleton_method(method) do |*args|
            self.instance_variable_set("@#{method[0..-2]}", args.first)
          end
        else
          self.define_singleton_method(method) do
            self.instance_variable_get("@#{method}")
          end
        end
        self.send(method, *args) rescue super
    end

    def map_features
        @features = {}

        singleton_methods.each do |m|
            m = m.to_s.chomp('=')
            unless m == "brand" || m == "model"
                @features[m] = self.send(m)
            end
        end
        @features
    end

end
```

Products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.new

        if map_features && @product.save!
            flash[:notice] = "Success: Your product was saved!"
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Failure"
        end
        redirect_to @product
    end

    def show
        @product = Product.last
    end

end
```

The **failing** cucumber step:

```
When(/^I upload the product with a "(.*?)" inch screen$/) do |screen_size|
  visit new_product_path
  fill_in('Brand', :with => @product.brand)
  fill_in('Model', :with => @product.model)
  fill_in('Screen Size', :with => screen_size)
  click_button 'Submit Product'

  page.should have_content("Success: Your product was saved!")
end
```

The **passing** Rspec example:

```
describe ProductsController do

    describe "listing an item" do 

        context "params with only brand and model" do
            it "creates an item without features" do
                params = {:brand => "Dell", :model => "N5050"}
                product = FactoryGirl.build(:product, params)
                product.map_features
                product.brand.should eq("Dell")
            end
        end

        context "params with brand, model, and 1 feature" do
            it "creates an item with 1 feature" do
                params = {:brand => "Dell", :model => "N5050", :screen => "15", :port => "usb"}
                product = FactoryGirl.build(:product, params)
                product.map_features
                product.features["screen"].should eq("15")
            end
        end
    end
```

The error I receive is:

```
undefined local variable or method `map_features' for #<ProductsController:0x0000000234d800> (NameError)
./app/controllers/products_controller.rb:24:in `create'
./features/step_definitions/new_product_steps.rb:12:in `/^I upload the product with a "(.*?)" inch screen$/'
features/new_product.feature:9:in `When I upload the product with a "15" inch screen'
```

Comment: Don't you want `@product.map_features` in your controller?

Comment: When I pull it out of my model the Rspec examples fail and the Cucumber steps still fail. At this point I just want to understand why it is failing. I haven't exactly decided if/where I should abstract it out to yet.

Comment: Its failing at the most basic level b/c `map_features` is not a defined method in the controller. Its an instance method of `Product` and therefore must be called on an instance of `Product`. I can't speak to any other problems there may be w/ the implementation, but fixing this is the first step.

Comment: Also note that what you seem to be attempting here is quite strange. I would not let it through a code review. If you're interested in storing random attributes about a product, I would recommend storing them within a common name in the form - something like `product[custom][screen_size]` and then overriding the `custom=` method in product to save the resulting hash.

Comment: The reason I set it up like this is because the products I work with have attributes that change frequently. I wanted to be able to append attributes to the form without having issues and when old attributes become obsolete I will not have to worry about changing the model or DB. When a new attribute is introduced the user will simply be able to click "add new attribute" on the form itself and it will append a new feature dynamically without having to edit the code myself. I felt like hardcoding too many attributes (besides what is not going to change frequently) wasn't flexible enough.

Comment: Why have you use the model's method in the controller here: `if map_features && @product.save!` ?

Comment: Not to mention the ProductsController spec tests the model, not the controller. It might pass, but it doesn't tell you anything about whether the controller works. Change it to `describe Product`.